# Oracle ODBC default database

Tags: database, windows, oracle, odbc

When I connect to databases with Windows ODBC such as MSSQL, it usually has the option to connect to a default database, however I did not find such an option in oracle database.
Does anyone know how to configure the default database for an Oracle ODBC Driver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the *TNS Service name* identifies the proper database.

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHekh.png]]

Long Answer:

Unlike other RDBMS like SQL server, you can't access multiple Oracle databases hosted on the same server through the same ODBC entry.

Oracle implements its own protocols and technologies to handle connections to its databases and one of them is the [TNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Network_Substrate).

TNS entries are defined by sysadmins or DBAs in a file called `tnsnames.ora`, and make the link between databases and users. A TNS entry specifies notably a *SID* which is a unique name for an Oracle database instance

You can read this for more info : [Using the Oracle ODBC Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1112)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How can I specify a specific Schema to connect to using the tnsnames.ora?

Comment: You can't. Do this in SQL :  `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = 'XXXXX' `